# How would I start a new line of images after the first 4?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code, and when I have more than 4 images, the images go off the screen like this
http://prntscr.com/64l0sw
How would I do it so after the first 4 images, it starts the new line of images instead of using my code to make a new page after every 4 images? My code is below
http://pastebin.com/rFg0CmWe

Comment: What have you tried so far? In my experience, you tend to get better feedback from the community here if you give them an attempt to troubleshoot, rather than asking for hand-holding.

Comment: pls consider to add your code here (well formatted), when your pastebin-link will broke, no one will be able to comprehend your question

Answer (score 1):

You can add a counter to your `while`-loop and check if there are 4 images and then add a break:

```
$i = 0;
while ($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($getItems)){

    if(($i % 4) == 0){
    //add page break e.g. new row in table or <br>
    }

    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done easily on client side. You can use responsive grid for example:

- [flex-gs](http://flexible.gs/)
- [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com)
- [Gumby](http://gumbyframework.com/)
- [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com/)
- [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)
- [Base](http://matthewhartman.github.io/base/)
- [Unsemantic](http://unsemantic.com/)